# Edit throwed error before catching?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I wanted to edit the `Error` object as its been thrown:

```js
try {
    throw Error('foobar')
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
}
```

I could do it this way:

```js
(function(status){try{throw Error('foobar')}catch(e){e.status=status; throw e}})(404)
```

However here it is throwing, catching, throwing [catching]. **Is there a way to only throw/catch once?**

#### Attempt

```coffee
{Types}      = require 'mongoose'

exports.valid_access_token = valid_access_token = (access_token, cb) ->
    unless Types.ObjectId.isValid access_token
        return cb ((err) ->
            err.name = 'ValidationError'; err)(Types.ObjectId access_token)
    # Rest omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score 2):

You can throw any arbitrary object or set necessary properties before throwing:

```js
try {
    var error = new Error('foobar');
    error.status = 404;
    throw error;
} catch (e) {
    alert('Error: ' + e.status + ', ' + e.message);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, however I'm using an external library (mongoose.Types.ObjectId) which throws its own error. I am checking if it will throw an error (using isValid) then am returning it (in a cb). I'd like to set the `status` attribute before it's thrown.

Comment: Edited my question with an attempt